# How to solve 503 error accessing CollabNet Subversion Console?

Tags: subversive, subversion-edge

I'm using Collabnate Subversion Edge.
I'm getting below error when trying to access URL http://localhost:3343/csvn.
Collbnate is set up on Windows Server 2008.

`HTTP ERROR: 503`
`Problem accessing /csvn/. Reason:`
`Service Unavailable`
`Powered by Jetty://`

How to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent two days fighting with the same problem. It turned out that CollabNet Subversion Edge 4.0.11 does not support Java 8.

The following procedure helped me make CN Subverion Edge 4.0.11 work again on Windows 7:

1) Uninstall CollabNet Subversion

2) Uninstall Java 8 (I had Java 7 and 6 side by side, so after uninstalling the 8, 7 picked up after I added it to PATH variable. It is important to add it at the very beginning of the path, otherwise Windows\System32\java.exe will be taken, which was not good for me also)

3) Install CollabNet Subverion (the important thing is to uncheck the "Run CollabNet ..." check box in the final screen. It looks like the installer is still creating files at the end and only after I have clicked OK in the final screen the needed configuration files have been created in data/conf folder.

4) Make sure that data/conf/httpd.conf file is created. If it is there, got to services (services.msc) and start server manually

Now launch the browser and navigate to localhost:3343/csvn.
Good luck.

Comment: This saved me some time re Java 8. Incidentally, you don't need to uninstall Collabnet - navigate to csvn\svcwrapper\bat, after getting the java installs correct, and run uninstallService.bat followed by installService.bat - this sorts out the java edition used by the service.

Answer (score 3):

1) Install Java 7

2) In file \csvn\svcwrapper\conf\wrapper.conf change from #wrapper.java.command.maxVersion=1.6 to wrapper.java.command.maxVersion=1.7

3) Run \csvn\svcwrapper\bat\runConsole.bat

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check in c:/csvn/data/logs for a log that starts with "console". Then find the error(s) and check what is wrong.

Did you try restarting the service ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, CollabNet Subversion Edge version 4.0.4. In my case the problem was updating the JAVA_HOME from JDK 1.6 to JDK 1.7.

I finally resolved it changing the file:
C:\PROGRA~1\csvn\svcwrapper\conf\wrapper.conf

I changed the value of the property: wrapper.java.command:java
wrapper.java.command=C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java

So the csvn now runs with 1.6 as before. And it works again as a service automatically.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative issue that results in the same error: The database may get corrupted. This is what just happened to me. The above answers where not working in this case. As Subversion Edge 5.0.1 comes *bundled* with jre8, it would be rather strange if it weren't able to run against it.

To solve the problem, I had to patch the database (luckily, the user database c:\csvn\data\csvn-production-hsqldb.script is a plain text sql file).

- Backup files in c:\csvn\data
- Delete csvn-production-hsqldb.script and start the service (should come up now)
- Exit the service
- Save the file which is automatically recreated now
- Compare your old file and the new working one
- Replace every line starting with `INSERT INTO QRTZ` in your database with the corresponding lines from the working copy
- Copy the new files to the proper place
- Start the service
- Hope it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Upgrade to SubversionEdge 5.1.4 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We encounter this problem with CollabNet Subversion Edge 3.3.1 every time we patch our JDK 6 install (e.g. IAVM update).  We need to install JDK 7 and 8 on this machine also so the installers are confusing the version information in the Windows Registry (not too much of a surprise there).  Even if we update JDK 6 last, it gets weird too.

Nevertheless, it turns out the Subversion Console uses the Windows Registry to locate the Java install to launch the Console service.  Updating the registry entry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion` to `1.6` and having a proper install of JDK 1.6 will restore console operation.