# how to run SVN (Collabnet Edge 4.0.12) explicitly with JRE 1.7, when 1.8 is installed?

Tags: svn, jvm

I am running Collab.net SVN Edge 4.0.12 on a computer with Win 7 Pro x64 SP1. Recently I have updated the Java runtime to 1.8. After that I have found that I cannot access the web interface (`http://localhost::3343/csvn/`) any longer. I get the error

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /csvn/. Reason:  
Service unavailable
```

I did some research and found, that this SVN Edge installation seems to be incompatible with JRE 1.8: [How to solve 503 error accessing CollabNet Subversion Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316634/how-to-solve-503-error-accessing-collabnet-subversion-console)

I could return to JRE 1.7 now, but I would like to keep the version 1.8 because it is needed for other things.
Is there a way to explicitly tell SVN Edge to use the JRE 1.7, without modifying the PATH variable? Maybe in `csvn\svcwrapper\conf\wrapper.conf`?

I already checked the solution of the following site:
https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=516736&orderBy=createDate&orderType=desc
but the Reg entry `ImagePath` at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CSVNConsole` already points to 1.7 (I think because I installed SVN Edge when 1.7 was the latest JRE on the computer). And when analyzing the processes using Sysinternals ProcessExplorer, I can see a java.exe that executes exactly that command of `ImagePath`. But there is a 2nd java.exe, which was called by the first, and this one is of the JRE 1.8 ...  #confused#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Windows registered all the JREs, try set the wrapper.java.command.maxVersion configuration to 1.7, i.e. wrapper.java.command.maxVersion=1.7.

Hopefully it will work for you just as well as for me. Note that configuration can be located in csvn\svcwrapper\conf\wrapper.conf file.